# Select and manipulate elements in DOM in XML document in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, object, dom

I would like to select elements from the DOM of an XML document in jQuery

This is what I have so far (the XML would usually come from another source not a string but this isn't relevant in this case):

```
var $xml = prepareXml('<measurement date="24/12/14" ammonia="0" nitrite="0" nitrate="20"></measurement><measurement date="25/12/14" ammonia="0" nitrite="1" nitrate="40"></measurement><measurement date="26/12/14" ammonia="1" nitrite="4" nitrate="55"></measurement>');

function prepareXml(string) {
    var string_xml = string;
    var xml_doc = $.parseXML(string_xml);
    var $xml = $(xml_doc);
    return $xml;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
$('measurement').each( function() {
    var date = $(this).attr('date');
    var ammonia = $(this).attr('ammonia');
    [...]
});
```

etc...

How can I select elements from attribute and access the DOM in the XML document rather than the HTML page the javascript is running from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$xml` variable can be populated with just `$(string)`

---

Then you can use the `$xml` as the context.

```
$('measurement', $xml).each(...)
```

or the equivalent `$xml.find('measurement')`

A good idea though, is to have a root element in your live xml because `.find` (*and the context way*) will not match those on the first level. (*unless you use `.filter`*)

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I was looking for! Now though jQuery says my XML is invalid: `[Error] Error: Invalid XML: [...]` `error (jquery-min-latest.js, line 2)
 parseXML (jquery-min-latest.js, line 4)
 prepareXml (js.js, line 11)
 (anonymous function) (js.js, line 3)
 j (jquery-min-latest.js, line 2)
 fireWith (jquery-min-latest.js, line 2)
 ready (jquery-min-latest.js, line 2)
 J (jquery-min-latest.js, line 2)` Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: @user3002189 how are you getting the XML ? Ajax calls ?

Comment: I just surrounded the current elements with a <document> element and the problem went away. Thanks for the help, you seriously advanced my little project :)

Answer (score 1):

First problem with your code is that your data is not valid XML. A valid XML document must have one top level element but your string has multiple `measurement` elements at the top level. In the following example, I've wrapped them in a `foo` element. This works:

```
var xml = '<foo><measurement date="24/12/14" ammonia="0" nitrite="0" nitrate="20"></measurement><measurement date="25/12/14" ammonia="0" nitrite="1" nitrate="40"></measurement><measurement date="26/12/14" ammonia="1" nitrite="4" nitrate="55"></measurement></foo>';

var $xml = $($.parseXML(xml));

$('measurement', $xml).each(function () {
  console.log(this.tagName);
});
```

Note that using `$($.parseXML(xml))` is **not generally equivalent** to doing `$(xml)`. When you use `parseXML` the DOM tree created is a actual XML document, with XML nodes in it. They have semantics that differ from HTML nodes. When you use `$(xml)` you are creating an HTML DOM tree. One difference is if you check the `tagName` field. In an XML document, it is case-sensitive and reflects exactly what was in the XML source. In a HTML document, it is normalized to upper case. Another difference is if you serialize the nodes. For instance, *in general*, an HTML tree with empty elements won't serialize the elements using the `<name/>` notation, but an XML tree will.